# Proving set identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Are these sets identical? 
How do you disprove or approve this set identity? 
Is it saying $A - B$ and $A\text{ or }B$ is equal to nothing? little confused,
help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To be in $A\smallsetminus B$, an element must not be in $B$. To be in $A\cap B$, an element must be in $B$. Hence, to be in $(A\smallsetminus B)\cap(A\cap B)$, an element must both be in $B$ and not be in $B$. Hence, there is no element in $(A\smallsetminus B)\cap(A\cap B)$, thus, it is an empty set.

In general, the sign $\cap$ means: an element is in $C\cap D$ if and only if it is **both** in $C$ and in $D$.